# Converting timestamp to LocalDate in JPA native query

Tags: java, date, jpa, nativequery

I am using JPA. I have a simple native query on some columns. One of them, named `CreateDate`, is in timeStamp format. When I run the native query, I get an `Object[]` in which `createDate` appears in `char[]` format. Is there any way to have the returned `char[]` for `createDate` in Java `LocalDateTime` or `Date` format?

Comment: show the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: You can convert it manually. Post `char[] createDate` returned from db

Comment: I can parse char[] to date, but i afraid what if someone changes db config so returned apearance of timestamp changes and my parser won't work. is this valid issue?

Comment: Thanks,answer is: LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(o[1].toString()); where o[1] is my returned object ,char[], from db